# Why is Mechanize not following the link

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am trying to follow a link with Mechanize but it does not seem to be working, syntax appears to be correct, am I referencing this incorrectly or do I need to do something else?

**Problem area**

```
agent.page.links_with(:text => 'VG278H')[2].click
```

**Full Code**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'open-uri'

agent = Mechanize.new

agent.get ("http://icecat.biz/en/")

#Show all form fields belonging to the first form
form = agent.page.forms[0].fields

#Enter VG278H into the text box lookup_text, submit the data
agent.page.forms[0]["lookup_text"] = "VG278H"
agent.page.forms[0].submit  #Results of this is stored in Mechanize agent.page object

#Call agent.page with our results and assign them to a variable page
page = agent.page

agent.page.links_with(:text => 'VG278H')[2].click

doc = page.parser
puts doc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should grab a copy of Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or something that allows you to watch what happens when you submit the form from your browser. Anyway, your problem is that this part:

```
agent.page.forms[0]["lookup_text"] = "VG278H"
agent.page.forms[0].submit
```

is returning an html fragment that looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><script>self.location.href="http://icecat.us/index.cgi?language=en&new_search=1&lookup_text=VG278H"</script>
```

So you actually need to call this directly or scrap out the the self.location.href and have your agent perform a get:

```
page = agent.get("http://icecat.us/index.cgi?language=en&new_search=1&lookup_text=VG278H")
```

If you were going to do that, this works:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'open-uri'

agent = Mechanize.new 

agent.get ("http://icecat.biz/en/")

page = agent.get("http://icecat.us/index.cgi?language=en&new_search=1&lookup_text=VG278H")

page = page.links_with(:text => 'VG278H')[2].click

doc = page.parser
puts doc
```

Happy scraping

Comment: The code above gives the same results as my original code, was that your intended outcome?

Comment: really? I don't see how that could be possible. Did you try it exactly as written compared to what you posted? Your code fails with: tmp/s1.rb:19:in `<main>': undefined method `click' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError), my code returns the result page.

Comment: oops sorry, you're right I didn't paste the correct code! Corrected (I  left out this bit: page = page.links_with(:text => 'VG278H')[2].click)

Comment: Super, that worked perfectly. I have multiple search terms so I should be able to reuse your code for that, maybe add an array like this lookup_text=<array>[0..10] . I may need another question soon :)